# Leaflet Draw revertLayers not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am developing a web map application using Leaflet.  The app enables users to draw objects on the map using the Leaflet Leaflet.Draw plugin.  Users can also edit or delete a drawn object.

I am having some problem with the revertLayers function in Leaflet Draw. When the user cancels the changes, the layers are reverted to their original state but in the next edit it shows the points for dragging the object nodes were not reverted.

[image]

This is my code for the edit control:

```
var editCtrlOptions = {
    featureGroup: editableLayers,
    selectedPathOptions: {
        maintainColor: true,
        opacity: 0.3
    }
}

var editCtrl = new L.EditToolbar.Edit(map, editCtrlOptions);

// On edit button click 
$('body').on("click", "#btn-edit", function() {
    // enable the edit control
    editCtrl.enable(); 
});

// On save edit button click
$('body').on("click", "#btn-edit-save", function() {
    // commit any changes made by the user
    editCtrl.save();
    // disable the edit control
    editCtrl.disable(); 
});

// On cancel edit button click
$('body').on("click", "#btn-edit-cancel", function() {
    // revert any changes made by the user
    editCtrl.revertLayers();    
    // disable the edit control
    editCtrl.disable(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be to do with the 0.3.0 version of the Leaflet.Draw plugin.  I changed to version 0.2.7 and the problem was gone.